# Is there any difference in meaning between "call a company back" and "call back in to a company"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Could you tell me if there ss there any difference in meaning between *call a company back* and *call back in to a company*? For example:

> When you are providing a customer with a solution, make sure that the solution is adequate so that they won't have to **call** the company **back**.
>
> When you are providing a customer with a solution, make sure that the solution is adequate so that they won't have to **call back in to** the company.

Comment: To ***call the company back*** might mean to contact the company by telephone on a second or subsequent occasion. But it could also mean *ask the company to send a repairman / service engineer to your property / office* (to carry out remedial work on something they recently installed for you). On the other hand, if you ***call back in to the company***, that means *you* are going back to *their* premises (to pick something up?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Call the company back" is the idiomatic way of expressing what you mean. To 'call someone back' means to make a return, or repeated phone call.

"Call into a company" sounds more like making an in-person visit. For example, "*I'm going to call into the store*" would mean you were going to visit the store; "*I'm going to call the store*" would mean you were going to telephone them.

The only time we really use "call into" (or "dial into") in relation to phone calls is in connection with services such as conference calls (eg "I'm going to dial into the meeting"). In British English, telephoning your employer to say you are unwell is known as "calling in sick", and we might say someone "called in" for that purpose.